# The autotools condition test traditionaly has an extra "x"

Tags: autotools, m4

When writting test in autotools it seems to be traditional to place the character `x` before variables that can potentially be empty so if they are empty you still get a string that is non empty:

```
AS_IF(
    [test "x$variablethatneedscheckingforempty" != "x"],
    [<True Block>],
    [<False Block>]
)
```

Depending on the situation the varaiable `variablethatneedscheckingforempty` usually takes the values `yes` or `no` or Empty/undefined.

Since the code is converted to shell `/bin/sh` before use this seems redundant. Or are there good reasons for placing the extra character in the string?